# Removing a list item until the list is empty

Tags: python, loops, random, rect

I currently have a grid displaying on my screen and one block being filled.  I would like every block to be filled with a random color.  So I would like to remove the `coords_list(random_coord)` from the list when its called so my `pygame.draw.rect` doesn't try to print a new color over top of an existing one.

An error occurs when I put the block of code starting from `from itertools import product` to `pygame.draw.rect.............`:

> coord_location = coords_list[random_coord] index is out of range

My code:

```
from itertools import product
coords_list = list(product(range(30,1170,30), range(30,870, 30)))

#random map co-ordinate
random_coord = random.randint(0,1065)
coord_location = coords_list[random_coord]
coord_loc_x = coord_location[0]
coord_loc_y = coord_location[1]
#Random color
random_choice = random.randint(0,2)
if random_choice == 0:
    terrain = blue
if random_choice == 1:
    terrain = green
if random_choice == 2:
    terrain = tan
##print(coord_location)
##random_terrain_type = terrain_types(random_choice)
pygame.draw.rect(screen, terrain, (coord_loc_x,coord_loc_y,30,30), 0)

line_start = 30
line_end = 30
top_line_start = 30
bottom_line_end = 30
for i in range(29):
    pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (30, line_start), (1170, line_end),1)
    line_start += 30
    line_end += 30
for i in range(39):
    pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (top_line_start, 30),     (bottom_line_end, 870), 1)
    top_line_start += 30
    bottom_line_end += 30
```

Comment: You should use `random_location = random.choice(coord_list)` instead of `random_coord = random.randint(0, 1065); random_location = coord_list[random_coord]`.  If you are modifying the list, the number of coordinates will be decreasing, and `1064`, for example, will be an invalid index.

Comment: Is there any need to assign random colours in random order? You have to assign a colour to every square, and the colours are random, so loop `for coord in coords_list: ...` and give each one a random colour that way? (And if you do want it in random order, you could `random.shuffle` it first)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `1065` in an out of range index

```
>>> coords_list = list(product(range(30,1170,30), range(30,870, 30)))
>>> len(coords_list)
1064
```

This means the maximum index is `1063` (python list indexes start at `0`)

Your random index function should be

```
random.randint(0,1063)
```

Or, if you don't want to hardcode the number, the `random` library also has

```
random.choice(coords_list)
```

Which will pick a random item from the list, whatever the length

Comment: No, they should be using a completely different function in the first place.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed one of the issues I was having.

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways of solving this. The main issue is with this block of code:

```
random_coord = random.randint(0,1065)
coord_location = coords_list[random_coord]
coord_loc_x = coord_location[0]
coord_loc_y = coord_location[1]
```

Way one is not dependent on squares being filled in a random order. We assume that every square needs to be filled so we just fill them in order with random colours:

```
for coords in coords_list:
  coord_location = coords
  coord_loc_x = coord_location[0]
  coord_loc_y = coord_location[1]
  #Random color
  random_choice = random.randint(0,2)
  if random_choice == 0:
    terrain = blue
  if random_choice == 1:
    terrain = green
  if random_choice == 2:
    terrain = tan
  ##print(coord_location)
  ##random_terrain_type = terrain_types(random_choice)
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, terrain, (coord_loc_x,coord_loc_y,30,30), 0)

  line_start = 30
  line_end = 30
  top_line_start = 30
  bottom_line_end = 30
  for i in range(29):
    pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (30, line_start), (1170, line_end),1)
    line_start += 30
    line_end += 30
  for i in range(39):
    pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (top_line_start, 30),     (bottom_line_end, 870), 1)
    top_line_start += 30
    bottom_line_end += 30
```

Way two will fill the squares in a random order with random colours:

```
import random
while len(coords_list) > 0:
  coord_location = random.choice(coords_list)
  coords_list.remove(coord_location)
  coord_loc_x = coord_location[0]
  coord_loc_y = coord_location[1]
  #Random color
  random_choice = random.randint(0,2)
  if random_choice == 0:
    terrain = blue
  if random_choice == 1:
    terrain = green
  if random_choice == 2:
    terrain = tan
##print(coord_location)
##random_terrain_type = terrain_types(random_choice)
  pygame.draw.rect(screen, terrain, (coord_loc_x,coord_loc_y,30,30), 0)

  line_start = 30
  line_end = 30
  top_line_start = 30
  bottom_line_end = 30
  for i in range(29):
    pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (30, line_start), (1170, line_end),1)
    line_start += 30
    line_end += 30
  for i in range(39):
    pygame.draw.line(screen, black, (top_line_start, 30),     (bottom_line_end, 870), 1)
    top_line_start += 30
    bottom_line_end += 30
```

Comment: Exactly! Your first solution is what I changed my code to be.  I was overly randomizing the process when all I wanted to do was fill every square.